# Forgot to add fermentable sugar

Tags: primary-fermentation, sugar, late-addition

I started a saison 3 days ago, and the recipe called for 3.5 oz of dextrose in addition to the grains.

The batch is a 1 gallon batch and the recipe also called for 1.6 lbs of 2-row and 6.5 oz rye.

Is it too late to add the sugar now, 3 days into primary fermentation? Of course I would make sure everything is sterile and would at the sugar dissolved in a couple ounces of water.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: 100g of dextrose won't change your beer much, but it's about the right amount for bottling. Are you sure it was meant to be in the primary?

Comment: Yes, I double checked the directions and the sugar was supposed to be added just at the start of the boil. I also forgot to mention that it's a 1 gallon batch, so 3.5 oz would be too much for bottling I suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too late to add the missing sugar. Just boil it in a small amount of water, but be sure not to burn it.

You'll want to use just a few ounces of water to avoid diluting the beer (or over filling the bottle?), so boiling on a stove will be tricky.

To get the absolute minimum amount of water, you could try dissolving and sanitizing the sugar in a pressure cooker. The solubility is just over 90%, and if I'm remembering chemistry right you could dissolve that in about 10ml of water, giving about 100ml of thick syrup.

Comment: So I added the sugar earlier today. Guess there was still lost of yeast floating around since it's started bubbling again. Looks like the beer is back on track. Thanks for the advice! :-)

Comment: Boiling table sugar for about 15 min invert it, separating fructose from glucose, which is more digestible to yeast. Can be made with about 1 to 1.5 parts of water for each part of sugar.